# Open URL in browser and take image snapshot in an automated fashion

Tags: c#, windows, screenshot

I was wondering if there was any way we could programmatically fire up an URL in a browser (i.e. firefox or google chrome), and take a snapshot of the webpage.

It would be awesome if this can be done in Linux environment. I do not have any lead on how to go about it; I can going to mark this in C# too - I'm willing to settle for Windows based approach also

Comment: If that was possible, it sounds like a huge security risk. You're talking about making an OS call from visiting a URL. If browser's end up supporting some hooks for screen-shotting themselves, then possibly. Otherwise, I'm pretty sure this type of interaction your looking can only be done if the user gives permission (kind of like when we have to click 'Allow' when installing a plugin). My two cents.

Comment: Security risk, uh? I'm or rather my computer is the user here. And I feed to my program what website to visit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) will pretty much do what you're looking for.  It uses [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/), the Chrome/Safari engine)

the `wkhtmltoimage` executable will take a URL and file save location arguments.

Windows/Linux/MacOS flavors.